# firewalld: outgoing NTP connection will be logged as blocked, but isn't blocked

Tags: centos7, logging, ntp, firewalld, chrony

I have configure firewalld on CentOS7 so it blockes all outgoing connections. Only the needed connections are white listed by adding some rules. Also I have add rules to enable logging of blocked connections (outgoing direction).

The current firewalld rules are (some IPs I have masquarade wit "xxx"):

```
/> firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-all-rules
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m udp --dport=53 -d 185.12.64.1 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m udp --dport=53 -d 185.12.64.2 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m owner --uid-owner root --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLIS -m owner -- uid-owner root -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=25 -d 193.111.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport=58443 -d 10.254.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport=58443 -d 193.111.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport=5667 -d 10.254.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m udp --dport=1194 -d 193.111.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner root -p tcp -m tcp --dport=443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner root -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner clamupdate -p tcp -m tcp --dport=443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -j LOG_OUTPUT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner chrony -p udp -m udp --dport=123 -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m owner --uid-owner root --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLIS -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=25 -d 2001:4ba0:XXXX:XX::X -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=58443 -d 2001:4ba0:XXXX:XX::X -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport=5667 -d fe80::bf18:c142:XXXX:XXXX -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m udp --dport=1194 -d 2001:4ba0:XXXX:XX::X -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner root -p tcp -m tcp --dport=443 -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner root -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner clamupdate -p tcp -m tcp --dport=443 -j ACCEPT
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner chrony -p udp -m udp --dport=123 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter LOG_OUTPUT 1 -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix 'FINAL_REJECT: '
```

The corrosponding iptable rules are (someone likes iptable's more as firewalld ...):

```
/> iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDI_XXXX
-N FWDI_XXXX_allow
-N FWDI_XXXX_deny
-N FWDI_XXXX_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N FWDO_XXXX
-N FWDO_XXXX_allow
-N FWDO_XXXX_deny
-N FWDO_XXXX_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N IN_XXXX
-N IN_XXXX_allow
-N IN_XXXX_deny
-N IN_XXXX_log
-N LOG_OUTPUT
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i enp0s31f6 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i tun0 -g FWDI_XXXX
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o enp0s31f6 -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o tun0 -g FWDO_XXXX
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDI_XXXX -j FWDI_XXXX_log
-A FWDI_XXXX -j FWDI_XXXX_deny
-A FWDI_XXXX -j FWDI_XXXX_allow
-A FWDI_XXXX -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A FWDO_XXXX -j FWDO_XXXX_log
-A FWDO_XXXX -j FWDO_XXXX_deny
-A FWDO_XXXX -j FWDO_XXXX_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -i enp0s31f6 -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -i tun0 -g IN_XXXX
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A INPUT_direct -p tcp -m set --match-set f2b-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT_direct -p tcp -m set --match-set f2b-f2bLongList src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT_direct -p tcp -m set --match-set f2b-blocklist_de src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 444 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_deny -m set --match-set badIPsSet src -j DROP
-A IN_XXXX -j IN_XXXX_log
-A IN_XXXX -j IN_XXXX_deny
-A IN_XXXX -j IN_XXXX_allow
-A IN_XXXX -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_XXXX_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 59943 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_XXXX_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9945 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_XXXX_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9944 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_XXXX_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9943 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_XXXX_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9947 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A LOG_OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
-A OUTPUT_direct -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 185.12.64.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 185.12.64.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p udp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 193.111.XXX.XXX/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 10.254.XXX.XXX/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 193.111.XXX.XXX/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 10.254.XXX.XXX/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5667 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -d 193.111.XXX.XXX/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 986 -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -j LOG_OUTPUT
-A OUTPUT_direct -p udp -m owner --uid-owner 993 -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT_direct -j DROP
```

The UDP port 123 (NTP protocol) is open for outgoing connections for user "''chrony''". If I call chrony manually from command line I get:

```
/> chronyd -q 'server 178.63.52.31 iburst'
2022-03-07T09:09:45Z chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-03-07T09:09:45Z Initial frequency -13.925 ppm
2022-03-07T09:09:49Z System clock wrong by 0.000131 seconds (step)
2022-03-07T09:09:49Z chronyd exiting
```

Ok, seems that works (like expected). But the firewall logs following:

```
Mar  7 10:09:45 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=24554 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55470 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:09:47 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25563 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=48110 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:09:49 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25796 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=46482 DPT=123 LEN=56
```

If remove the rules for Port "123":

```
/> firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner chrony -p udp -m udp --dport=123 -j ACCEPT
success
/> firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-rule ipv6 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner chrony -p udp -m udp --dport=123 -j ACCEPT
success
/> firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

and call chrony again:

```
chronyd -q 'server 178.63.52.31 iburst'
2022-03-07T09:12:46Z chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-03-07T09:12:46Z Initial frequency -13.925 ppm
2022-03-07T09:12:56Z No suitable source for synchronisation
2022-03-07T09:12:56Z chronyd exiting
```

(which fails like expected) I get 6 lines in the firewall log file (instead of 3 lines above):

```
Mar  7 10:12:46 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=30341 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45581 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:12:48 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32318 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=36395 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:12:50 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33178 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56503 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:12:52 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34311 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55691 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:12:54 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35963 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=57795 DPT=123 LEN=56 
Mar  7 10:12:56 static kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=136.243.139.67 DST=178.63.52.31 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37075 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51338 DPT=123 LEN=56
```

This behavior I have only with NTP connections. At example if I open a SMTP connection on port 25 to 193.111.xxx.xxx (which is explicitly allowed by the firewall rule) I get (like expected) no firewall log message.

Why I get firewall log messages of blocked UDP Port 123 connections when the port is explicitly allowed and chrony works like expected?

Comment: I think you might need to reorder the firewall rules to have the LOG_OUTPUT before the chrony-specific rule.

Comment: @mlichvar: You are right! The correct priority is 2 for the LOG rule and 3 for the DROP role! If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it. Thx